# Angular Best way to keep filtering , paging and sorting params when we go back from a detail view to list view

Tags: angular, sorting, parameters, pagination, filtering

I want to know the best way to keep filtering , paging and sorting params when I go to a detail view of a table's item and finally go back to the list view  in Angular ?

I've tried with localStorage items but it's realy heavy  and not easy to maintain..

Can you help me ?

Comment: You can use local storage to store the data and then recover it after the  transition to the list view. You can use a service method to `get` and `put` and `remove` params but you will need to implement it.

Comment: Thanks i'll try to implement a params service and store them in DB

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add them as query strings in your url... if you want to have everything after a refresh action. 
If you want to keep data between app tranzitions, why wont you create a storage service which could handle pagination/ filtering and paging ?

Comment: I have no tried yet, but the idea of a service looks great thanks !